# Ask about DBNULL to other types

Tags: c#, dbnull

hi am asking about my error see my screen shot, thanks

[DBNULL to other types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSSqz.jpg)
I create my c# code to read a excel file but something had a problem see above my screen shot

other problem , I inputted your code but will shown an error  see screenshot below

[Other Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Fq7.jpg)

Comment: include the snippet as well

Comment: What is the type of `row`?

Comment: The column (at index 8) in the row you're reading from is null. You can't store null in a decimal.

Comment: Thanks all of you,  to answer my question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what database library you're using, but most libraries built on-top of ADO.NET do not always use a .NET `null` reference to indicate a SQL `NULL` value. That's what `DBNull` is for (accessed via `DBNull.Value`). You can test for SQL `NULL` by using the Object Reference Equality operator `==` or `Object.ReferenceEquals`.

Your code is rather convoluted. I suggest you try this instead:

```
Object value = row[8]; // I don't know what `row` is, change this to be a more specific type if there are any type-safety constraints on `row[8]`.
if( Object.ReferenceEquals( DBNull.Value, value ) ) {
    // value is SQL NULL
}
else {
    // value is not SQL NULL, but it is not necessarily a Decimal value either

    if( value is Decimal ) {

        return (Decimal)value; // you can't use the shorthand `as` operator with value-types like Decimal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope that there may be a chance for `row[8]` to be `DBNull`. in such cases you can check that by comparing `row[8]` with `System.DBNull.Value`.
try like this:

```
if (row[8] != System.DBNull.Value))
{
   decimal quantity; 
   if(decimal.TryParse(row[8].ToString(), out quantity)
   {
      item.ONHANDQTY = quantity;
   } 
}
```

Comment: This is inefficient if `row[8]` is already a `Decimal` value instead of a string.

Comment: @Dai: yep you are correct in that sense. But I have considered `Convert.ToDecimal` in the OP's code

Answer (score -2):

use or (||) condition instead of and (&&) condition, as shown below:

```
if(onhand == "" || row[8] == System.DBNULL.value)
{
    //your code
}
else
{
    ONHANDQTY=Convert.toDecimal(row[8]);
}
```

Comment: `DBNull` and `null` are not the same.

Comment: okay sir , I try this thnaks